# iterative.ai MLEM | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mlem.api'; 'mlem' is not a package

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, pypi, modulenotfounderror, mlem

Goal: install and run Python script with [MLEM](https://mlem.ai/doc) code.

Following this [installation guide](https://mlem.ai/doc/install) in the library docs; `pip install mlem` should suffice.

**Code:**

```
from mlem.api import import_object

# ...
```

**Traceback:**

```
$ python3 app/deployment-poc/mlem.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/BitBucket/project/app/deployment-poc/mlem.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mlem.api import import_object
  File "/home/me/BitBucket/project/app/deployment-poc/mlem.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mlem.api import import_object
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mlem.api'; 'mlem' is not a package
```

---

I've installed both via `pip` and `conda`.

```
$ which mlem
/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/bin/mlem
$ mlem --version
 MLEM Version: 0.4.1
```

```
$ conda list
# packages in environment at /home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
fastapi                   0.89.1                   pypi_0    pypi
mlem                      0.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
```

```
(venv) me@laptop:~/BitBucket/project$ pip install mlem --no-dependencies
Requirement already satisfied: mlem in /home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages (0.4.1)
```

```
(venv) me@laptop:~/BitBucket/project$ pip show mlem
Name: mlem
Version: 0.4.1
Summary: Version and deploy your models following GitOps principles
Home-page: https://mlem.ai
Author: Mikhail Sveshnikov
Author-email: mike0sv@iterative.ai
License: Apache License 2.0
Location: /home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: aiohttp, aiohttp-swagger, cached-property, click, cloudpickle, dill, entrypoints, flatdict, fsspec, gitpython, importlib-metadata, isort, iterative-telemetry, Jinja2, pydantic, pyparsing, python-gitlab, python-multipart, requests, rich, typer
Required-by:
```

**Request to have a reputable member create new tag: `mlem`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a script `/home/me/BitBucket/project/app/deployment-poc/mlem.py` which shadows importable package `mlem`. With such a script `import mlem` in the script tries to import from the very script, not from the package.

Rename `mlem.py` to something different.

The bottom line: never name you scripts the same as importable packages. Never have `email.py` or `test.py`, etc.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I renamed it to `mlem_inference.py`

Comment: Any other errors I have are to do with separate libraries; so irrelevant to this post. Thanks; noted for future.

Comment: If possible; could you create `mlem` as a new post tag, please? Dw if not

Comment: @DanielBell99 https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mlem/info